# Number of adjacent and almost adjacent pairs of vertices in regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a $k$-regular (i.e., every vertex has degree $k$) undirected graph $G$.

I'm interested in counting pairs of vertices $(i,j)$ that are either at distance $1$ (i.e., adjacent), or distance $2$ (i.e., not adjacent but have at least one common neighbor).

More precisely, I'm interested in the proportion of such pairs relative to the total number $n(n-1)$ of pairs of vertices, where $n$ is the number of vertices of $G$. More more precisely, I'm interested in whether this proportion goes to $0$ if we keep $k$ fixed and $n$ goes to infinity.

The truth of this seems straightforward to me, both intuitively and from computer simulations (with random regular graphs). I'm just curious if there's a more precise way of counting such pairs. Or some bounds. Or something like that.

Two quick examples. First, say $G$ is a cycle (i.e., a $2$-regular graph) from $1$ to $n$. The adjacent vertices are $\{i, i+1\}$, a total of $\mathcal{O}(n)$ pairs; the vertices at distance $2$ are $\{i, i+2\}$, a total of $\mathcal{O}(n)$ pairs. Overall, $\mathcal{O}(n)$ pairs.

If $G$ is the complete graph (i.e., $(n-1)$-regular) every pair fits the bill. Overall, $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ pairs.

For $3$-regular graphs I'm already not sure how to count these pairs. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obviously it must go to 0. A vertex has at most $k(k-1)$ neighbors of second order. Thus take $n$ huge and the fraction of second order neighbors becomes arbitrarily small. I'm pretty confident that I don't know you nor that we have a common friend.